# Обработка массива объектов несколькими потокам C++

Tags: c++, ооп, многопоточность

В общем, существует массив некоторого класса, в дальнейшем потребуется обработать его элементы в нескольких потоках.
Есть мысль разбить массив на группы и отправлять их, однако столкнулся со сложностью разбиения.
Подскажите, как представить массив в виде групп.
Если это невозможно, то как отправлять элементы в разные потоки.

Comment: если использовать OpenMP или TBB, то там есть возможность организовать параллельный цикл, который сам тело цикла для разных индексов будет исполнять в разных потоках

Comment: Индексы "от" и "до" — чем не разбиение?